# Is there emacs-like incremental search in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, emacs, intellij-idea, incremental-search

I miss the emacs behavior for incremental search.  In emacs, we can do this:

> 1. C-s
> 2. key in search text, i.e. "button"

The first occurance of button will be found.  If you continue to press C-s, the next occurance will be found.  It seems to me that IntelliJ is close to this, except that you need to press a different keystroke for the second search.  To me, this gets annoying.  I would much rather press the same keystoke for the first as well as subsequent searches.

Is this possible in IntelliJ?  It works great in Eclipse with emacs keybindings.

Edit: I opened up a bounty on this question.  Is there an example of a similar implementation of this functionality written as a plug-in or patch to IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: alt+f3 does the trick. JetBrains does listen :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In newer releases of IntelliJ, incremental search uses arrow keys to navigate up/down on search term hits. E.g.:

1. C-s (if using emacs key-bindings)
2. key in search text
3. up/down arrow keys to navigate up/down through matching search terms

Answer (score 3):

There is a request in IDEA issue tracker submitted 2 years ago:
[Emacs-Mode: Incremental Search Again should be mapped to Ctrl-S,Ctrl-R after first search](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-18586).

As [IDEA is open source now](http://www.jetbrains.org/display/IJOS/Home), anyone can [submit a patch](http://www.jetbrains.org/display/IJOS/Contribute#Contribute-Coderelatedcontributions) implementing this feature and it will be committed to the next IDEA version.

Comment: So I guess JetBrains is not interested in adding this feature?

Comment: @Gray: *CrazyCoder* is one of the IDEA dev... JetBrains precisely open sourced IntelliJ IDEA so that **other** people can contribute too.